# Kotlin : Groupby the objects by 2 values, perform sum and then map it to other object

Tags: kotlin, group-by, collections

i am not very expert in kotlin collection functions so need some help:
Assume i have a data class:

```
data class transaction(val SenderName: String,val ReceiverName: String,val Amount: Int)
```

the list of transactions

```
val transactions = listOf(
transaction("Rahul","Ravi",10000),
transaction("Rahul","Ravi",-500),
transaction("Ravi","Rahul",1000))
```

First i want to group the entries based on the sender & receiver followed by adding the amounts. which i am able to do using the below code

```
transactions.groupBy { it.SenderName to it.ReceiverName}.map{entity ->
 val amountSum = entity.value.sumOf { it.Amount }}
```

after this what i want is to calculate the final amount of transactions between 2 persons from one person's reference. Like for example i calculate for Rahul's point of view then:
Sum of amount(where Rahul is Sender) - Sum of amount (where rahul is receiver)
which will be: 9500 - 1000 = 8500
and the final output should be:

```
data class NewObject(val reference_person:String, val Other_person :String, val FinalAmount:Int)

val finalList = [("Rahul","Ravi",8500),("Ravi","Rahul",-8500)]
```

I have gone throught many stackoverflow posts but don't know how to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
val finalList = (transactions + transactions.map {
    transaction(
        it.ReceiverName,
        it.SenderName,
        -1 * it.Amount
    )
}).groupBy { it.SenderName to it.ReceiverName }.map { entity ->
    NewObject(entity.key.first, entity.key.second, entity.value.sumOf { it.Amount })
}

println(finalList)
//[NewObject(reference_person=Rahul, Other_person=Ravi, FinalAmount=8500), NewObject(reference_person=Ravi, Other_person=Rahul, FinalAmount=-8500)]
```

What I first do is add to the original list the same list but with sender and receiver reversed. Then I group them like you did, and finally mapped them to `NewObject`s

Comment: if i also have date variable in the transaction entity then in the final NewObject list how can I get the max date of all the transactions entry between 2 people?